# pythonic way of splitting a list of lists into a length-keyed dictionary?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary

```
xs = [
        [1,2,3,4],
        [5,6,7,8],
        [9,0,0,1],
        [2,3],
        [0],
        [5,8,3,2,5,1],
        [6,4],
        [1,6,9,9,2,9]
]

""" expected output:

    xs_dict = {
        1: [[0]]
        2: [[2,3],[6,4]]
        4: [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,0,0,1]]
        6: [[5,8,3,2,5,1],[1,6,9,9,2,9]]
    }
"""
```

I can do this, for example, by

```
xs_dict = {}
for x in xs:
    aux = xs_dict.get(len(x),[])
    aux.append(x)
    xs_dict[len(x)] = aux

print(xs_dict)
```

But I can't help feeling there should be a more pythonic way to achieve this.

What is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
from itertools import groupby

xs_dict = {
    key: list(value)
    for (key, value) in groupby(sorted(xs, key=len), len)
}
```

As discussed in the comments below, the necessary sorting of the input is a step which is unnecessary costly.  For large input this will slow down this algorithm way more than necessary.  Consider using @hiroprotagonist's solution instead then, or replace the `groupby(sorted(…), …)` by a `groupby()` which can handle unsorted input.

Comment: i was missing the `sorted` and i was overwriting my keys.. Nice!

Comment: Yeah, actually I find it is a *wart* that `groupby()` needs sorted input.  Sorting is unnecessary expensive in general.  There should at least be a version which doesn't work like this but which collects actively.

Comment: damn! that is nice! +1

Comment: @hiroprotagonist Isn't this less efficient than your solution?

Comment: @Chris_Rands: you mean because of the sorting? maybe a little, i guess (did not `timeit`). otoh: dict-comps are usually very fast.

Comment: @Chris_Rands  You are absolutely right.  If we are talking about a list of millions of lists, then the sorting at some time overwhelms everything else.  As I said in a comment above, that is the ugly side of `groupby()`.  That `groupby(sorted(…), …)` should be replaced by a `groupbyOfUnsorted()` to be more efficient.  And as it stays, Hiro's solution is more efficient for large input (albeit less elegant ;-), so he got my ⁺¹ as well :)  (I edited my answer to include this fact.)

Comment: Yah I think we agree but `groupbyOfUnsorted()` is basically the `defaultdict` solution or would you implement it another way? @hiroprotagonist

Comment: @hiroprotagonist Yes, `defaultdict` could be used then.  I'd prefer the `setdefault()` solution you mentioned in your answer, though.

Comment: we seem to agree on everything (elegance, efficiency, ...!). @Alfe: yes i'd also prefer `dict.setdefault` (which i feel is underrated [at least here on SO i see it very rarely]). @Chris_Rands: no, i would not implement it any other way.

Comment: What a rare treat that we all agree, how civilized, thanks anyway both

Comment: https://code.activestate.com/recipes/580800-groupby-for-unsorted-input/ implements a `groupby()` for ungrouped input.

Answer (score 5):

you could use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

xs_dict = defaultdict(list)
for item in xs:
    xs_dict[len(item)].append(item)
```

python `dict`s also have a nice method called [`setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=setdefault#dict.setdefault) (that way you do not need to import anything):

```
xs_dict = {}
for item in xs:
    xs_dict.setdefault(len(item), []).append(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pprint
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import groupby

xs = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [5, 6, 7, 8],
    [9, 0, 0, 1],
    [2, 3],
    [0],
    [5, 8, 3, 2, 5, 1],
    [6, 4],
    [1, 6, 9, 9, 2, 9]
]

data = defaultdict(list)

for result, group in groupby(sorted(xs, key=len), len):
    for item in group:
        data[result].append(item)

pprint.pprint(dict(data))
```

Gives me

```
{1: [[0]],
 2: [[2, 3], [6, 4]],
 4: [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 0, 0, 1]],
 6: [[5, 8, 3, 2, 5, 1], [1, 6, 9, 9, 2, 9]]}
```

Answer (score 0):

1 liner:

```
res = {len(s): [d for d in xs if len(d) == len(s)] for s in xs}
```

Comment: This does several thing twice.

Comment: never said it is efficient :P

Comment: @afifit You also never said it wasn't xD. It simply scales badly

Comment: I guess you can optimize it a bit by changing the `xs` into a set of length, still no perfect though